# SpringMVC, Shiro, and Java Configuration

Tags: spring-mvc, shiro

I am trying to use Shiro 1.2.2 with my SpringMVC 3.2.3   I have seen several examples of how to configure Shiro using ini files.  But we are using JavaConfig and I have only found one partial example on that.  I have several @Configuration files:

```
public class EdmWebInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    private static final String DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME = "dispatcher";
    private static final String DISPATCHER_SERVLET_MAPPING = "/*";

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext root = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    root.scan( "com.company.config" );
    root.register( EdmConfiguration.class, SecurityConfig.class );
    servletContext.addListener( new ContextLoaderListener( root ) );

    ServletRegistration.Dynamic appServlet = servletContext.addServlet( DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME,
            new DispatcherServlet( root ) );
    appServlet.setLoadOnStartup( 1 );

    Set<String> mappingConflicts = appServlet.addMapping( DISPATCHER_SERVLET_MAPPING );
    servletContext
            .addFilter( "shiroFilter", new DelegatingFilterProxy( "shiroFilter", root ) )
            .addMappingForUrlPatterns( null, false, DISPATCHER_SERVLET_MAPPING );

    servletContext.addFilter( "Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter",
            org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.class ).addMappingForUrlPatterns(
            null, false, "/*" );
```

My beans are defined here:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.company.service", "com.company.utility",
        "com.company.controller", "com.company.utility.startup",
        "com.company.security", "com.company.security.model" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ImportResource({ "classpath:applicationContext.xml"})
@PropertySource({ "classpath:application.properties", "classpath:mail.properties" })
public class EdmConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {


    @Resource
    private Environment environment;

    @Autowired
    private org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.WebSecurityManager securityManager;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BoneCPDataSource dataSource = new BoneCPDataSource();

    ...
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();

        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory( entityManagerFactoryBean().getObject() );

        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public DelegatingFilterProxy springSecurityFilterChain() {
        return new DelegatingFilterProxy();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource( dataSource() );
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan( environment
                .getRequiredProperty( PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN ) );
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass( HibernatePersistence.class );

        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        ...
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties( jpaProperties );

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslator exTranslator() {
        return new HibernateExceptionTranslator();
    }

    @Bean(initMethod = "init")
    public StartupListener startupListener() {
        return new StartupListener();
    }




    @Bean
    public ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean contentNegotiationManager() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty( "xml", "application/xml" );
        properties.setProperty( "json", "application/json" );
        properties.setProperty( "html", "application/html" );

        ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean contentNegotiationManager = new ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean();
        contentNegotiationManager.setFavorParameter( true );
        contentNegotiationManager.setMediaTypes( properties );
        contentNegotiationManager.setDefaultContentType( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON );

        return contentNegotiationManager;
    }



    @Bean
    public JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender() {
        JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        int port = Integer.parseInt( environment.getRequiredProperty( "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port" ) );
        mailSender.setHost( environment.getRequiredProperty( "mail.smtp.host" ) );
        mailSender.setPort( port );
        mailSender.setUsername( environment.getRequiredProperty( "mail.login.username" ) );
        mailSender.setPassword( environment.getRequiredProperty( "mail.login.password" ) );

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty( "mail.smtp.auth", environment.getRequiredProperty( "mail.smtp.auth" ) );
        properties.setProperty( "mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true" );
        mailSender.setJavaMailProperties( properties );

        return mailSender;
    }


    @Bean
    public VelocityEngine getVelocityEngine() throws VelocityException, IOException {
        VelocityEngineFactory factory = new VelocityEngineFactory();
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put( "resource.loader", "class" );
        props.put( "class.resource.loader.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader" );
        factory.setVelocityProperties( props );
        factory.setResourceLoaderPath( "/com/edelweissco/dental/templates" );
        factory.setPreferFileSystemAccess( false );
        return factory.createVelocityEngine();
    }

    @Bean
    public StandardPasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new org.springframework.security.crypto.password.StandardPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilter() {
        ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilter = new org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean();
        shiroFilter.setSecurityManager( securityManager);
        return shiroFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn(value = "lifecycleBeanPostProcessor")
    public DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator defaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator() {
        DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator creator = new DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator();
        creator.setProxyTargetClass(true); // it's false by default
        return creator;
    }
```

I have broken the Shiro configuraton into its own file:

```
    @Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public CustomSecurityRealm customSecurityRealm() {
        return new CustomSecurityRealm();
    }

    @Bean
    public SaltAwareJdbcRealm saltAwareJdbcRealm() {
        return new SaltAwareJdbcRealm();
    }

    @Bean
    public org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.DefaultPasswordService passwordService() {
        return new DefaultPasswordService();
    }

    @Bean
    public TempFixPasswordMatcher passwordMatcher() {
        TempFixPasswordMatcher tempFixPasswordMatcher = new TempFixPasswordMatcher();
        tempFixPasswordMatcher.setPasswordService( passwordService() );
        return tempFixPasswordMatcher;
    }


    @Bean
    public WebSecurityManager securityManager() {
        DefaultWebSecurityManager securityManager = new DefaultWebSecurityManager();
        securityManager.setRealm( saltAwareJdbcRealm() );
        return securityManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public LifecycleBeanPostProcessor lifecycleBeanPostProcessor() {
        return new LifecycleBeanPostProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public MethodInvokingFactoryBean methodInvokingFactoryBean() {
        MethodInvokingFactoryBean methodInvokingFactoryBean = new MethodInvokingFactoryBean();
        methodInvokingFactoryBean.setStaticMethod( "org.apache.shiro.SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager" );
        methodInvokingFactoryBean.setArguments( new Object[]{ securityManager() } );
        return methodInvokingFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn(value = "lifecycleBeanPostProcessor")
    public DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator defaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator() {
        return new DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor authorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor() {
        AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor authorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor = new AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor();
        authorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor.setSecurityManager( securityManager() );
        return authorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor;
    }
```

When I try to deploy I get exceptions such as :

This is the full stack trace I get once I remove the @Transaction from my OfficeService:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'menuService': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'menuRepository': Post-processing of the FactoryBean's object failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy68]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy68
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4937)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1551)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:835)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:622)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:569)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:835)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:771)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1455)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:75)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1296)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1388)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:819)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:303)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'menuRepository': Post-processing of the FactoryBean's object failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy68]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy68
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:165)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:102)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1454)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:442)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:416)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:550)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:150)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:303)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy68]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy68
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:217)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:111)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:477)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:362)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.postProcessObjectFromFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1625)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:162)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy68
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:446)
    at org.springframework.cglib.transform.TransformingClassGenerator.generateClass(TransformingClassGenerator.java:33)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:377)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.create(Enhancer.java:285)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:205)
    ... 72 more
Nov 9, 2013 4:10:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

Comment: Post your `MenuRepository` and `MenuService` classes.

Answer (score 5):

Presumably you have some `@RequiresAuthentication` or `@RequiresRole` annotations on your service classes. To enable those, Shiro (Spring) has to proxy the beans it creates. It does this with the `DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator` bean. However, this bean proxies with JDK proxies which create proxies based on interfaces, not on base classes.

For example, say Spring has to proxy `OfficeService`, it'll create a `java.lang.reflect.Proxy` instance that wraps the `OfficeService` bean. If you called `getClass()` on this object, it would return something like `com.sun.proxy.$Proxy64`. If your `OfficeService` was implementing any interfaces, that object would be an instance of those interfaces. However, the bean is not an instance of `OfficeService`, so Spring can't use it as an `@Autowired` target.

Instead, you have to tell Spring to use CGLIB proxies. You can do that by changing your config here

```
@Bean
@DependsOn(value = "lifecycleBeanPostProcessor")
public DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator defaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator() {
    DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator creator = new DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator();
    creator.setProxyTargetClass(true); // it's false by default
    return creator;
}
```

And adding the CGLIB libraries (jars) to your classpath.

---

Note that if this is not a Shiro issue, you need to post the rest of your config. If you are doing any other proxying in your context, you'll need to do something similar to disable JDK proxies.

It seems like the only other thing that can create proxies is the transaction management, so change to

```
@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true)
```

Comment: I do not have any @RequiresRole or anything yet. I am just trying to get the Shiro configuration in so I can configuring it.  I have the cglib 2.2 in my dependencies already for spring usage.  I added the DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator bean but I still get errors.  I was able to put Shiro in by replacing my SecurityConfig with shiro in a applicationcontext.xml. However, that resulted in no session being created, probably because of servlet filters.  And, I really would prefer to have all my configuration in Java.  I am updating my post with current configuration.

Comment: @sonoerin See my edit. Transaction management also requires proxies. Does your `OfficeService` class have `@Transactional` on any of its methods? Add the config I specify in my edit.

Comment: I added the EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true) to my configuration class but it didn't make a difference.  When I removed the @Transaction from my OfficeService, I get a different exception on deploy:  Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy68]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy68

Comment: @sonoerin Edit your question and post the full stack trace.

Comment: Thank you for your patience and help.  I have updated my question with the current stack trace.

Comment: I have been wondering if this is related to AOP, but when I created an Interface for my classes flagged in the exception, it doesn't seem to change anything.  Is aspect something that Shiro requires?  I don't see any references in the sample projects they provide.

Comment: @sonoerin They don't use Aspects, but they do proxy instances to add some aspect-like behavior similar to transaction management.